# What is the difference between $provide.decorator and module.decorator?

Tags: angularjs

Quoting the Angular [developer guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators)

> module.decorator
>
> This function is the same as the $provide.decorator function except it is exposed through the module API. This allows you to separate your decorator patterns from your module config blocks.

So basically what is the difference here? Are there scenarios when one method is preferred over the other? Why not always use module.decorator?

Answer (score 1):

`Module.decorator` was introduced as a shortcut for `$provide.decorator` in 1.4. `$provide.decorator` may be still used for backward compatibility.

The obvious property of `$provide` methods is that function scope has access to both provider and instance injectors:

```
app.config(($provide, $compileProvider) => {
  $provide.decorator('linkService', ($delegate) => {
    $compileProvider.aHrefSanitizationWhitelist(...);
    return $delegate;
});
```

Less obvious but still important property of `$provide` methods is that they affect the application after config phase, while module methods don't, this creates the possibilities for lazy loading and other undocumented but potentially beneficial techniques:

```
app.config(($provide) => {
  $provide.value('$provide', $provide));
});

app.run(($provide) => {
  // app.decorator('service', ...) will do nothing here
  $provide.decorator('service', ...);
});

app.run((service) => { ... });
```